AudioManager cannot change audio volume within a Notification Channel
I want a notification channel can emit sound and user can change the volume of that specific audio whenever they want. I can change the sound easily through AudioManager in the example below:
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn_play = findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        btn_pause = findViewById(R.id.btn_pause);

        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        second_audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.remind);


        //currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        btn_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play(v);
            }
        });
        btn_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pause(v);
            }
        });

        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
            {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        });
    }

    public void play(View view){mediaPlayer.start();}
    public void pause(View view){mediaPlayer.pause();}

Everything is simple and works fine.
However, when I embed the scripts above (actually only 2 lines):
audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, (value set by user), 0);

the audio volume simply freezes at the level set at the first time. I know that the audio volume and also the audio itself cannot be changed once the channel is built. To allow user change the audio volume, I delete the old channel and re-build a new one. However, I CANNOT change my audio volume EVEN I HAD DELETED THE CHANNEL AND RE-BUILD A NEW ONE.
Why can't I change my audio volume when I embed the script in the notification channel build script? What shall I do to fix the problem?
Here is how I build my notification channel
CreateChannel(String alarm_type, int ratio)
{
            Remind_Channel_ID = "Remind_Channel_ID_" + String.valueOf(ratio);
            Log.e("Remind channel ID", Remind_Channel_ID);
            Remind_Channel_name = "Remind_Channel_name_" + String.valueOf(ratio);
            Remind_ratio = ratio;
            String remind_description = "Channel For Alarm Manager";


            Uri remind_soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                    "://"+ myactivity.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.remind);

            NotificationManager remind_notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) mycontext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            int remind_importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

            NotificationChannel remind_channel = new NotificationChannel
                    (Remind_Channel_ID, Remind_Channel_name, remind_importance);
            remind_channel.setBypassDnd(true);
            remind_channel.enableLights(true);
            remind_channel.setLightColor(-16776961);
            remind_channel.setDescription(remind_description);
            remind_channel.enableVibration(true); // enable vibration
           

            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
            remind_channel.setSound(remind_soundUri, audioAttributes);
            
            // Now change the audio volume
            remind_audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, Remind_ratio, 0);
            remind_audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.MUSIC, Remind_ratio, 0);
            
            remind_notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(remind_channel);
}

